# SSIS - Execute Package Task - file or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

What is the best approach to execute a package within another package?

**1.From SQL Server?**

In this case, I have to deploy the child package everytime the master package is executed

**2. From file**

In this case, I am forced to deploy all packages as files (not to SQL Server). Then local package path will not be the same with the package path from the server...

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using from file.

This allows me to use source control for a way to deploy the files. Also in SQL 2012 and higher you can actually do DIFFs on SSIS Package Files.

If you want to try and keep the path the same, maybe you could try a mapped directory on your localhost. That way you could for example create a E: drive that maps to a location on C. This will allow you to keep in sync between local and server locations.